# .htaccesss Remove the File Extension and Variables From the URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, parameters, get, file-extension

I know this has been asked many times but no matter what I try I still cannot get my code to work. I have this .htaccess file and I want to redirect my code from this:

```
example.com/news/articles.php?id=21&artName=Hello-World
```

to this :

```
example.com/news/articles/21/Hello-World
```

Currently I have this code in my .htaccess file:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^news/articles/([\w-]+)/(.+) news/articles.php?id=$1&artName=$2 [QSA,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
RewriteRule !\.php$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [QSA,L]
```

This is the href link to that article:

```
<a href="https://www.example.com/news/articles/21/Hello-World">Article</a>
```

Whenever I try to go to that page. I get a "Error 404- Not Found" Page. I am new to editing the .htaccess file so please let me know what I am doing wrong in my code so I can see a successful rewrite in my link, thank you.

Comment: then you should be using: `RewriteRule ^news/articles/([\w-]+)/(.+) news/articles.php?id=$1&artName=$2 [QSA,L,NC]`

Comment: Ok I copy pasted your rewrite rule into my code it still gives me the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this at top of your .htaccess to disable `mod_spelling` choices:

```
<IfModule mod_speling.c>
   CheckSpelling off
   CheckCaseOnly off
</IfModule>

Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^(news/articles)/([\w-]+)/(.+) $1.php?id=$2&artName=$3 [QSA,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

[This will disable multiple choice option.](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_speling.html#checkcaseonly)

> **Summary**
> Requests to documents sometimes cannot be served by the core apache server because the request was misspelled or miscapitalized. This module addresses this problem by trying to find a matching document, even after all other modules gave up. It does its work by comparing each document name in the requested directory against the requested document name without regard to case, and allowing up to one misspelling (character insertion / omission / transposition or wrong character). A list is built with all document names which were matched using this strategy.

Comment: Also test with this rule: `RewriteRule ^(news/articles)/([\w-]+)/(.+) /$1.php?id=$2&artName=$3 [QSA,L,NC,R]`

Comment: I get multiple choices error when I request /news/articles instead of /news/articles.php

Comment: Sorry it didn't work, When I use only that rewrite rule it switches my link back to /news/articles.php?id=21&artName=Hello-World

Comment: When I copy your entire answer to my .htaccess file I still get the 404 Error

Comment: `it switches my link back to /news/articles.php?id=21&artName=Hello-World` that was just a test rule to show you that rule works fine. Now rename `articles.php` to `foobar.php` and also replace `articles.php` with `foobar.php` in my answer and retest

Comment: Yeah I did, but I dont think the error is ocuring because of capitaization, I think the multiple choices error is showing up because the link is /news/foobar/9/Hello-World and the browser wants me to use /news/foobar.PHP/9/Hello-World. it is not recognizing that the Rewrite condition is changing foobar.php to foobar

Comment: your Options -MultiViews saved my life, turns out that my hosting service requires me to have RewriteBase / in the file for it to work after I did that, I used Options -MultiViews and it Worked for me, Thanks for everything, you saved my life.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have already added a `news/` prefix on the directive as stated in comments then you need to remove the following rule block as well:

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
> ```

This is incorrect and will cause the following rewrite to `/news/articles.php` to be skipped. This does the same thing as later directives anyway (and the later directives are "better").

Comment: Indeed this is also a problem

Comment: I have made that change as well but I still get the same cursed error, I have also updated my post to match what I have after the suggestions.

Comment: Do I have to reset Apache or something for this change to take place or is it instantaneous.

Comment: Also I was told to have this Options -MultiViews but I am not sure what it does at all.

Comment: All changes in `.htaccess` should be instantaneous, unless you are seeing a cached response... make sure your browser cache is cleared. Yes, you need `Options -MultiViews` here because your URL `/news/articles` matches a file of the same basename, ie. `articles.php`. If MultiViews was enabled then it would serve `articles.php` without your URL parameters. (Although MultiViews _should_ be disabled by default.)

Comment: Is your 404 response generated by Apache or your script?

Comment: If you request `example.com/news/articles`, does it serve `articles.php` (without parameters)?

Comment: when I request example.com/news/articles it serves a multiple choices error it goes as follows: "The document name you requested (/news/articles) could not be found on this server. However, we found documents with names similar to the one you requested." Then it tells me that Available Documents are: /news/articles.php (common basename)

Comment: Hhhmm, that's a bit of a weird error - looks like your server has a custom 404 document that is trying to be helpful (although that could be a security vulnerability). However, that also means your other rule to append the `.php` extension isn't working either. Try adding some "nonsense" to the start of the file - do you get an error? (You should get a 500 Internal Server Error if your `.htaccess` file is being processed at all.)

Comment: when I request/click on: /news/articles.php I find my page loaded without the Get_ parameters so it looks broken. and when I write /news/articles/9/Hello-World I still get the same broken page without it identifying the Get_ varaibles

Comment: "when I write /news/articles/9/Hello-World I still get the same broken page" - I thought you said this generated a 404? ... "Error 404- Not Found"

Comment: Sorry I'm a noob here, I dont know what you mean by "Try adding some "nonsense" to the start of the file - do you get an error? " but when I requested this: https://www.example.com/nonsense/articles.php I got another 404 error

Comment: Literally write some gibberish eg. "nonsense" at the start of the `.htaccess` file. This should generate a syntax error.

Comment: I did that and got a Internal Server Error.  it reads as follows: The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Ok, that's expected. It means that your `.htaccess` file is being processed at least.

Comment: However, please see comment above.... "when I write /news/articles/9/Hello-World I still get the same broken page" - initially you stated this resulted in a "Error 404- Not Found", but now you're saying it's the same as when requesting `/news/articles.php`?!

Comment: I also used to have a chache policy in my .htaccess :
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2628000, public" I dont know if its affecting my code right now

Comment: sorry for the confusion, When I request /news/articles/9/Hello-World I get the 404 Error  but when I request /news/articles.php the page loads but it does not collect the Get_ method parameters so it looks broken without it identifying the ID and Name

Comment: and when I request news/articles I get a multiple choices error and the browser wants me to redirect to /news/articles.php

Comment: I have both a news directory and a news php file, the news file is in a different folder, but I am using the directory in this code not the file, not sure if this affects my code but I wanted it to be known.

Comment: To clarify, do you have any other `.htaccess` files along the filesystem path?

Comment: In my main diectory there is only one .htaccess file but in the main directory there is alsoa  folder titled logs, and inside it there is a .htaccess file as well. inside the logs directory there is another folder titled traffic.html and it too has another .htaccess file inside. So i could find a total of 3 .htaccess files in my directory.

Comment: The other `.htaccess` files (on a completely different file path) would not affect this. To clarify, when you request `/news/articles.php?id=21&artName=Hello-World` directly - the page does display OK?